# How to redraw DataTables by destroying and drawing again in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to redraw a datatable component with the following lines:

```
$('#table').DataTable().destroy();
$('#table').DataTable();
```

The problem is that when I execute the lines above the table is being drawed twice like if `.destroy()` is never executed. Thew weird thing is that if I execute both functions from the console separately or using two buttons... then the code just works. Am I running into some `async` issue or something like that?.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '/api/contratistas?nombre=' + this.inputValue,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    resp = data; 

                    $('#table').DataTable().destroy();
                    $('#table').DataTable();
                },
                async: false
            });
```

Which would be the best way to solve this?.

Comment: If you're loading data via ajax, use `$('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: @freedomn-m with the above code replacing the two lines with .ajax.reload() does not work

Comment: Are you loading the data via ajax?

Comment: This ajax request fills a vue.js variable that is the one that keeps the datatable updated

Comment: So, no, so the above "if loading via ajax" doesn't apply.

Comment: So try redrawing the table rather than destroying and recreating it `$('#example').DataTable().draw();` https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: doesn't work either... the table keeps redrawed twice...I will try with array of promises